# qmake not finding opencv package when built from within Qt creator

Tags: macos, qt, opencv, qmake

I am fairly new to the Qt environment and I am running into an error when I try to build. I am also new to StackOverflow so pardon me if I miss format. When I run `qmake` from the command line it finds the `opencv` package and generates a Makefile, however when I run it from Qt Creator, it fails to find OpenCV.

Here is my .pro file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-03-24T21:23:01
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = cvtest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
CONFIG+=link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG+=opencv
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

I think it has to do with fully qualifying the path to qmake. 
If I run

> qmake /Users/matt/untitled1/untitled1.pro -r -spec macx-g++ CONFIG+=x86_64

on the command line it works fine, however if I fully qualify the path to qmake in the manner that Qt Creator does it;

> /Users/matt/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/bin/qmake /Users/matt/untitled1/untitled1.pro

I get the following error:

> Project ERROR: Package opencv not found

Any ideas on how to make this work in Qt Creator without going to the command line?

Comment: Use `which qmake` to check if you're actually running `/Users/matt/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/bin/qmake`. My bet is that you have qt 4.8 installed from macports and are inadvertently using that from Qt Creator.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your .pro file:

```
QT_CONFIG -= no-pkg-config
```

I believe Qt for the Mac is built with the `--no-pkg-config` configure option.

Comment: Full solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972066/using-pkg-config-with-qt-creator-qmake-on-mac-osx).